# Adding class using attr() in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran into an error while trying to output this in my html file, the JS looks like this:

```
$.getJSON('products.json', function(data){
    $.each(data.products, function(i, f){
        var launch = "<div"
        + attr("class", "testClass")
        + ">"
        + f.buyLink
        + "</div>"
```

If I remove the attr, it works, however it returns me with an Uncaught Reference Error. What it does is that it takes data from a json and outputs it to a div on a html file but I can't seem to add a class to it using javascript.

Edit: It was meant to be a class in such a way that it outputs:

```
<div class="testClass">f.buyLink</div>
```

Comment: add code with attr()

Comment: In `"<div"
        + attr("href", f.buyLink)
        + ">"`, JS is expecting `attr` to be a function but its not available and hence throws error.

Comment: that is NOT how you build dom elements with jquery. Either go full jquery or full string manipulation.

Comment: div element has no href attribute

Comment: Apologies, typo on my end, it was meant to be a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either make it as a string:

```
var launch = "<div"
        + ' class="'+ f.buyLink + '"')
        + ">"
        + f.buyLink
        + "</div>
```

Or you create the element and use the `attr()` attribute.

```
var launch = $('<div>');
launch.attr("class", f.buyLink);
// alternative, note that f.buylink then should not have a dot!!
// launch.addClass( f.buyLink );
launch.text(f.buyLink);
```

or shorthand:

```
var launch = $('<div>').attr("class", f.buyLink).text(f.buyLink);
```

You can't use them combined as in your code.

Comment: href on divs doesn't really make sense, though :)

Comment: `href` on div? Did you missed that?

Comment: @Ionut: meaningless as that may be, maybe that's what OP really wants. Who knows.

Comment: It doesn't make sense no... but hey, if that is what the OP wants... he can gets it :)

Comment: btw, in your jquery, you can just chain all the things. That would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry it was meant to be class lmao

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var launch = "<div class='testClass'>"+f.buylink+"</div>";
```